# Why the copy constructor is called when I add a different object which is an argument in copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

I don't understand why the copy constructor is called while i am adding e to c.

```
struct A {};
struct B {
    B() { std :: cout << "B Constructor" << std :: endl; }
    B(const A&) { std :: cout << "B Copy" << std :: endl;}
    const B operator +(const B& arg);
};

const B B::operator +(const B& arg) {
    std :: cout << "+" << std :: endl;
    return B();
}

int main() {
    B c;
    A e;
    c + e;
}
```

Comment: `B(const A&)` is a converting constructor, not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the copy constructor being called, it's

```
B(const A&);
```

The copy constructor always has such a signature:

```
B(const B&);
```

As you haven't provided one, the compiler generates a copy constructor for you, but this one is indeed not called: you have an `operator+` for `B`, which accepts a `const B&`, but the other operand is of type `A`. As the constructor mentioned first (`B(const A&)`) is *implicit*, this works out - a temporary `B` is instantiated from the `A` object named `e`, and the operator is invoked.

To make the output in your example more intuitive, consider changing the constructor `B(const& A)` to

```
B(const A&) { std::cout << "Construct B from A\n"; }
```